# Output all terms slugs for a loop filter

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, filters, slug

I have created a filter on a custom post type loop using terms slugs just like that :

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo esc_attr( $cat->slug ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $cat->name ); ?> </a></li>
```

and

```
<div class="grid-item <?php echo esc_attr( $cat->slug ); ?> js-isotope-item js-grid-item">
```

But several posts are linked to multiple taxonomy terms and $cat->slug just take the first slug..

Is there any way to call all the slugs and output them with a separator (space) to have different classes ?

Sorry if I'm not clear, english is not my language..

Thank you for help !

Comment: Where do you set the value for `$cat`?

Answer (score 0):

To print or to call all the slugs, you can use the following codes.

```
<?php 
$cats = get_the_terms(get_the_id(), 'your-taxonomy-id');
   if( is_array($cats) ){
      foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
           echo $cat->slug.' ';
       }
   }
?>
```

For more details, follow the below link.
[Add custom category name as data-filter to switch between these categories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318302/add-custom-category-name-as-data-filter-to-switch-between-these-categories/318314#318314)